# Installation failed with message:Installed cancelled by user

Tags: android

Installation failed with message INSTALL_CANCELED_BY_USER.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

what should i do..my app was working till now but today when I ran it again it shows the message...I have tried lots of solution already answered but  then 
also its not working ..I have also tried multidex application "true' .

Comment: did you use contentProvider? maybe it's wrong package name in content provider

Comment: try to install it on emulator, is it still has problem?

Comment: it has been solved..i had to on the install via usb  option in my phone..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so anyone else won't make this stupid mistake:

My problem was that I left my phone at my table, and it actually asked if I want to install it with a 10 second timeout. (No, I don't want to install it, that's why I hit install in Visual studio tho :O)

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings of your phone. go to option install via usb.and turn it on.
I got the error resolved by doing this.
Hope this helps others too with this problem.